# jQuery: How to loop through multidimensional array

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, loops

I am new to jQuery and hope someone can help me with this.

I have an Ajax call with the success function (`data`) returning an array like the below.

Now I have to **loop through this and for each "tID" I have to do something with the corresponding "content".**

I was thinking of using something like the following but couldn't figure out how to apply this here:

```
$.ajax({        
    type: "post",   
    url: "ajax.php",
    cache: "false",
    data: {
        node: 'fetchContent',
        tIDs: tIDs
    },
    success: function(data){
        $.each(data.arr, function(index, value){
            console.log(value.content);
        });
    }
});
```

Can someone help me with this ?

**Example array (Ajax result):**

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["tID"]=>
    int(1)
    ["content"]=>
    string(6) "Value1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["tID"]=>
    int(2)
    ["content"]=>
    string(6) "Value2"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["tID"]=>
    int(3)
    ["content"]=>
    string(6) "Value3"
  }
}
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: In what format does `.ajax.php` return your data?

Comment: Can you post the actual response. Whatever format it's currently in is very hard to read.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: That's the example array I posted.

Comment: @George: I think this is the same as Rory's question. I updated the post to show this better.

Answer (score 4):

You can use nested `for loop` for the same:

```
var i,j,arrayItem;
for (i = 0; i < outerArray.length; ++i) {
    arrayItem = outerArray[i];
    for (j = 0; j < arrayItem.length; ++j) {
        console.log(arrayItem[j].tID);
        console.log(arrayItem[j].content);
    }
}
```

Edit(after discussing with OP):

There is no need for 2-D array, 1D array is more suited, so the array becomes:

```
var data= [
 {
      "tID" : 1,
      "content": "Value1"
  },  
  {
      "tID" : 2,
      "content": "Value2"
  },
  {
      "tID" : 3,
      "content": "Value3"
  }
];
```

And the `for loop` becomes:

```
for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    console.log(data[i].tID);
    console.log(data[i].content);
}
```

See the fiddle : "http://jsfiddle.net/Lvkbtuwz/1/"

Comment: Thanks for this ! The ajax result in my case is called data so would I have to replace "outerArray" with "data" in your solution ?

Comment: Yes replace "outerArray" with "data". You are most welcome :)

Comment: Thanks - I already tried that but then I am getting undefined in the console.

Comment: Can you share your exact array please.

Comment: The array looks exactly like the example in the post, I just replaced the values and shortened it.

Comment: Thanks a lot - also, I could make modifications on the PHP side (as per Infira's suggestion) if that helps here.

Comment: I think you are unnecessarily creating 2-d array, see the fiddle "http://jsfiddle.net/Lvkbtuwz/1/"  is this you want? See the console for results

Comment: Thanks ! I think you are right. :) The fiddle is not working for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83717/discussion-between-nikhil-batra-and-tanemahuta).

Answer (score 2):

In php you have to return not array but json_encode($array)

then you can use the array as Object in JS.

-----Edit---21.07.2015
if array in PHP looks like this

```
echo json_encode(array(0 => array("name" => "Gen"), 1 => array("name" => "Peter")));
```

**Notice the sequential array indexes 0,1*

then the json will look like this, can be used as array each element as object

```
[{"name":"Gen"},{"name":"Peter"}] //and then can you iterate using
$.each(arrayFromPhp, function (index, obj)
{
    console.log(obj.name); //will output gen and Peter
});
```

But if you array in PHP looks like this

```
echo json_encode(array(3 => array("name" => "Gen"), 8 => array("name" => "Peter")));
```

**Notice the  array indexes are not sequential 3,8*

Then the JSON looks likes this are not array any more

```
{"3":{"name":"Gen"},"8":{"name":"Peter"}}
```

Then you have to iterate like this

```
for (i in arrayFromPhp)
{
    console.log(arrayFromPhp[i].name) //will output gen and peter
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this ! If I do this on PHP side what would I use for the loop in jQuery then ?

Comment: Update: I think this might be the way to go here as it simplifies the jQuery part but I would still need some guidance on how to handle this then.

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea of iterating through arrays can be achieved using javascript.

arrays have `forEach` function where your could iterate through the array elements. Use the following example to build your solution.

**Asuming you get a JSON response.**

```
var response = JSON.parse(ajaxRespons);
response.forEach(function(element,index){
    element.forEach(function(innerElement,index){
     //access ur inner elements here
    })
})
```

The above is just an idea. You would have to do some trial runs to get the idea.